# SPF Record Fails - How to verify Server IP Address and managing multiple SPF records

Tags: spf, mx-record, cname-record

I'm trying to verify the mail sent by our server. With our current DNS settings, sending mail from our server shows an **SPF Neutral** response.

I tried adding a combination of my server's IP and Domain.

```
v=spf1 a mx ipv4:XXX.XX.XXX.XX -all
v=spf1 include:mydomain.com -all
```

Both these records showed no change, all mail sent from the server was still Neutral. So I tried combining all my existing SPF records like so:

```
v=spf1 a mx include:mydomain.com ipv4:XXX.XX.XXX.XX include:cmail1.com include:mail.zendesk.com -all
```

I tested sending mail again and now get a **SPF Fail** response.

I've looked extensively online and I can't see how to fix my DNS entries so I can get a  PASS on the SPF records. I don't know if I need additional CNAME, A, MX, or I'm missing something entirely.

I'm using a Plesk server with a fixed IPv4 address and using CloudFlare to manage my DNS and Name Servers.

Here is what a full fail response looks like:

```
SPF:    FAIL with IP XXX.XX.XXX.XX
spf=fail (google.com: domain of accounts@mydomain.com does not designate XXX.XX.XXX.XX as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=accounts@mydomain.com
Received-SPF: fail (google.com: domain of accounts@mydomain.com does not designate XXX.XX.XXX.XX as permitted sender) client-ip=XXX.XX.XXX.XX;
spf=fail (google.com: domain of accounts@mydomain.com does not designate XXX.XX.XXX.XX as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=accounts@mydomain.com
```

Comment: What is the TTL on your DNS records look like? how long did you wait to test after making the changes?

Comment: FIXED. I just spent forever talking to my provider and we couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Be careful! I copied my code from a site which said to use ipv4, it should be ip4! (no v)

Comment: damn, i totally missed that too. If you put that as a self-answer it'll help others who come by later see it :)

Answer (score 1):

FIXED. I just spent forever talking to my provider and we couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Be careful! I copied my code from a site which said to use ipv4, it should be ip4! (no v)

Answer (score 0):

While fixing your single syntax error (`ipv4` instead of [`ip4`](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#ip4)) seems to have fixed your problem, it's still not the only problem with your SPF record. That's why it's always a good idea to read the official documentation to understand the issue.

- The first one you figured out already in your question by trial and error, but [RFC 7208 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-3.2) is the source that tells it clearly: you should combine your SPF rules for a single hostname as a single `TXT` record.

  > A domain name MUST NOT have multiple records that would cause an authorization check to select more than one record.
- You should understand what the [`include` mechanism](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax#include) actually does: the specified *domain* is searched for a match i.e. looked for more SPF rules. Your `include:mydomain.com` suggests that you try use it like `a` mechanism. If this is in `mydomain.com. TXT`, it's a reference that tries to include self!

  You should also revise all your other `include`s and see that they actually have an SPF record. You should [only `include` existing records](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes#include).

  > **Warning**: If the domain does not have a valid SPF record, the result is

> a permanent error. Some mail receivers will reject based on a
> `PermError`.

- If your `a` or `mx` resolves to the same IP address than `ip4` they are unnecessary and should be removed. [List a server only once](http://www.openspf.org/FAQ/Common_mistakes#only-once).

  > Ultimately, SPF lookups resolve to an IP address.

> If the server's IP rarely changes, consider using the `ip4:x.x.x.x` (or
> `ip6`) notation so recipients can avoid DNS lookups entirely. Since
> there is a limit of 10 DNS lookups per SPF record, specifying an IP
> address or address range is preferable for long lists of outgoing mail
> servers.
>
> Often an SPF record can be condensed down to something like `v=spf1 ip4:x.x.x.x -all` if there is only one outgoing mail server.

Reading through both the linked articles for SPF syntax and common mistakes is a really good overview of the whole subject. The linked RFC adds all the technical details, if you are also interested in how it works.

Comment: Great points, thank you Esa. I did remove the mydomain.com include as I realised fairly quickly this was totally wrong.